# Zero dimensional ideals and their primary decomposition

Tags: commutative-algebra, vector-spaces, ideals

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over a field $k$, and $I$ a zero dimensional ideal with a primary decomposition $I=\cap Q_i$. Why is $\sum \dim_k S/Q_i = \dim_k S/I$?

Comment: What do you mean by *zero dimensional ideal*?

Comment: Dear Rodrigo, Do you see why there is a natural embedding from the  $\prod_i S/Q_i$ to $S/I$?  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I am confused because I actually wanted to say more. Why isn't this map an isomorphism? We have that $\cap Q_i = \prod Q_i$, since the $Q_i$ are coprime. Doesn't the Chinese remainder theorem imply that they are isomorphic? Also, where does the assumption that $I$ is zero dimensional come into play? I assume from what you said that it is for getting the inequality $\dim S/I \le \sum \dim S/Q_i$

Comment: @ucf sorry, I was imprecise last time. A zero dimensional ideal is an ideal such that every prime ideal containing it is maximal.

Comment: Dear Rodrigo, Yes, what I asked about gives the inequality in one direction.  There will always be an embedding $S/\cap Q_i \hookrightarrow \prod_i S/Q_i$ no matter what the $Q_i$ are, but this won't be an isomorphism in general.  (Think about the case when $S = k[x,y]$, $Q_1 = (x)$, $Q_2 = (y)$.)  You have to use zero-dimensionality to get the isomorphism.  (As you say, it has to do with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.)   Regards,